# Where are the NSLayoutPriority constants in MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to find these constants in Xamarin.iOS currently - but can't find them.

```
enum {
   NSLayoutPriorityRequired = 1000,
   NSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh = 750,
   NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow = 510,
   NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut = 500,
   NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCannotResizeWindow = 490,
   NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow = 250,
   NSLayoutPriorityFittingSizeCompression = 50,
};
typedef float NSLayoutPriority;
```

Which C# object are they provided in?

Comment: there for MonoMac: http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:MonoMac.AppKit.NSLayoutPriority, but it looks like they aren't exposed in xamarin.ios :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it's named `UILayoutPriority` in iOS. From the `NSLayoutConstraint.h` file of the iOS 6.1 SDK:

```
@property UILayoutPriority priority;
```

`UILayoutPriority` is an enum inside `MonoTouch.UIKit` namespace.

Comment: Thanks - everything else was NS-based in iOS - so didn't think of looking there :)